# Angular - Jasmine - How to test an action inside an interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I want to test with jasmine the following method:

```
  public init(): Subscription {
    return interval(100).subscribe(() => this.doSomething())
  }
```

I would like to test the method `doSomething` is executed, when the `init` function is called. I spy the method `doSomething`.

I have tried following tests:

```
it('interval should call doSomething', () => {
    const mySpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'doSomething');
    subs.push(service.init());
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

or that:

```
it('interval should call doSomething', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mySpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn<any>(service, 'doSomething');
    subs.push(service.init());
    tick(200)
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

For the second test I am getting the following error: `Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.`

How can I trigger the interval from the test, or how can I wait for the execution of the interval?

Comment: Here is my spec file for my library's service, it has a lot of fake async tests. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache/blob/master/projects/ngx-rxcache/src/lib/rxcache.service.spec.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
discardPeriodicTasks();
```

after your expect.

Comment: Why is discardPeriodicTasks() necessary to be called, if I am using fakeAsync and tick? Why are there pending timers? Is it be süße I am using a tick of 200ms and the interval triggers every 100ms?

Comment: I am not sure, I just read an article on how to test async operations and that is the way it has worked for me.